# Japanese and Chinese translation fails on MAC

Tags: c++, macos, internationalization, wxwidgets

I am working on an application that is internationalized to support quite a few languages. However, I see an issue with the Japanese and Chinese Languages. Strings which have a variable embedded in between them appears as blank. This behavior is seen only on Mac.

```
wxString strMessage = wxString::Format(
    _("Do you want to delete \"%s\" ?"),
    GetStr());

wxMessageDialog dlg(this, strMessage, _("Title"),
    wxYES_NO | wxYES_DEFAULT | wxICON_EXCLAMATION);
```

In the code sample above, I am trying to display a warning message. This warning message is displayed correctly in all other languages like Dutch, French, Spanish etc. However, in Japanese and Chinese a dialog box is shown with a blank string. On windows it works well with all languages, this issue is only with MAC.

What am i missing here?? :-O

Comment: I guess it's a text encoding issue. The languages you mention can all be represented by single byte per character but Japanese and Chinese require multibyte. Have you checked you have actually read the Japanese string correctly ?